# svn upgrade help needed (1.6.5 to 1.6.???)

Tags: svn, upgrade

My svn server is Subversion 1.6.5, and I want to upgrade to at least 1.6.6 to fix the [svn externals-by-file bug for binary files](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3368).

But I'm not sure which binaries to use -- things have gotten a bit weird since Apache took SVN over from Tigris.

Server configuration (it's not a heavyweight server):

- Windows XP
- Apache for handling the HTTP server (SVN + several other applications)
- Atlassian Crowd for handling authentication + interoperating w/ JIRA and Fisheye

I've looked at Collabnet, they don't seem to offer just the binaries anymore, they have this ["Subversion Edge"](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion/) thing, but it includes Apache and I can't afford to screw up my current Apache configuration.

The other [prepackaged binaries](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) listed on Apache's website seem a little iffy to me; I don't know which one(s) will work and are from a source I can trust.

Any advice? Do I have to worry about repository upgrades with a 1.6.5 -> 1.6.x executable upgrade?

Comment: I can only wish you good luck :) , and make sure you back up your repo before you do anything crazy. :) I use VisualSVN (http://www.visualsvn.com/) on my WHS because it is the easiest to manage IMO, and so far I have no problem upgrading it.

Comment: based on your comment on @David answer, you choose WanDisco. Then how about now, did you found any issue? Can it integrate with Crowd/JIRA very well?

Comment: Crowd/JIRA -- pretty easy, the hard part of it was the apache <-> crowd connector which if I remember was a weird Perl script. Now they seem to have something more ready-to-use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Subversion Edge distribution from CollabNet and simply not use the Subversion Edge part of the product. You can also just not take their Apache install either. The CollabNet product will contain everything you need. Just ignore the stuff you don't need.

You can also try the WanDisco distribution. WanDisco is a company that makes other products that uses Subversion, and its developers heavily participate in the Subversion project. There's been some tension in recent months with WanDisco over on the Subversion lists. The CEO made some [strange statements](http://jaxenter.com/asf-and-wandisco-clash-over-subversion-33237.html) that sounded like they were threatening to fork Subversion. However, WanDisco has backed down on those statements and everything is cool.

And, I've personally have tried the SlikSVN binaries and had absolutely no issues with them. They work great. However, I don't believe they have a server or Apache bindings.

Comment: :-( I tried both Subversion Edge and WanDisco. Neither installer gave me any options to install/not install an Apache server. Grr.

Comment: Collabnet loses. >:( The mod_dav_svn.so and mod_authz_svn.so seems to work at first glance, but I tried copying the .dll and .exe from their /bin directories to run svn.exe, and it gave me an error. I can't tell what I need to keep and what I can live without, so I really can't use it. sigh.

Comment: WanDisco svn 1.6.15 looks better, more akin to the "base" svn. I think it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how upgrading goes, but I recently downloaded and installed the 1.6.15 version from slikSVN:

http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/

Everything works AOK.